# How to save the editor in a RCP-Perspective?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, perspective

In my RCP-Plug-In-Project I have a view and an editor. I have also set a perspective, in which the view and the editor is created.

The problem is that the content of the editor (described in the `createPartControl`-method) is not shown. If I change the `run configurations` and set `clear` in `Workspace Data`, I get the default perspective and when I click `Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Other...`, I can choose my "BDD Perspective" and the editor with its content and the view is visible. [Perspective with editor and view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhW0B.png)
If `clear` in `Workspace Data` is unset, my "BDD Perspective" appears, but with an empty editor. [Perspective with empty editor and view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKk8P.png)

**Does anybody know how to make the content of the editor visible in a user-defined perspective?**

Here is the relevant code. In the perspective is a handler called "CallBDDEditor", that opens the editor:

```
public class Perspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {

String ID = "bddperspective";

@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {

    String editorArea = layout.getEditorArea();

    IFolderLayout right = layout.createFolder("right", IPageLayout.RIGHT, .15f, editorArea);
    right.addView(DiagramView.ID);

    IViewLayout viewLayout = layout.getViewLayout(DiagramView.ID);
    if (viewLayout != null) {
        viewLayout.setCloseable(false);
        viewLayout.setMoveable(false);
    }
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(true);
    layout.setFixed(true);
    try {
        new CallBDDEditor().execute(null);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
    IPerspectiveRegistry perspectiveRegistry = window.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry();
    IPerspectiveDescriptor personalPerspectiveDescriptor = perspectiveRegistry.findPerspectiveWithId(ID);

    if (page != null && personalPerspectiveDescriptor != null) {
        page.savePerspectiveAs(personalPerspectiveDescriptor);
    }
}}

public class CallBDDEditor extends AbstractHandler {

public static final String ID = "bdd.klighd.openBDDEditor";

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
    try {
        page.openEditor(new BDDEditorInput("test of editor input"), BDDEditor.ID);
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isHandled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void removeHandlerListener(IHandlerListener handlerListener) {
}}

public class BDDEditor extends EditorPart {

public static final String ID = "bdd.klighd.BDDEditor";
boolean dirty = false;
private String formula_ = "f(x,y,z) = x!y + z!x";

ToolItem inputItem_;
ToolItem showItem_;
ToolItem simplifyItem_;
ToolItem removeItem_;
ToolItem cancelItem_;
Composite parent_;
ToolBar bar_;
private Label formulaLbl_;

@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
    super.setSite(site);
    super.setInput(input);
}

@Override
public boolean isDirty() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    parent_ = parent;
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    parent_.setLayout(layout);
    formulaLbl_ = new Label(parent_, SWT.NONE);
    formulaLbl_.setText("");
    bar_ = new ToolBar(parent_, SWT.BORDER | SWT.VERTICAL);

    // create items
    inputItem_ = new ToolItem(bar_, 0);
    showItem_ = new ToolItem(bar_, SWT.PUSH);
    simplifyItem_ = new ToolItem(bar_, SWT.PUSH);
    removeItem_ = new ToolItem(bar_, SWT.PUSH);
    cancelItem_ = new ToolItem(bar_, 0);

    // set text on items
    inputItem_.setText("INPUT");
    showItem_.setText("SHOW");
    simplifyItem_.setText("SIMPLIFY");
    removeItem_.setText("REMOVE");
    cancelItem_.setText("CANCEL");

    // disable show-, simplify-, remove- and cancelItems
    showItem_.setEnabled(false);
    simplifyItem_.setEnabled(false);
    removeItem_.setEnabled(false);
    cancelItem_.setEnabled(false);

    DropdownSelectionListener listenerInput = new DropdownSelectionListener(inputItem_);
    listenerInput.add("As String", true);
    listenerInput.add("From File", false);
    inputItem_.addSelectionListener(listenerInput);

    bar_.pack();
    parent_.pack();
}

public IEditorInput getEditorInput() {
    return super.getEditorInput();
}

@Override
public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
}

@Override
public boolean isSaveAsAllowed() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void setFocus() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}

@Override
public void doSaveAs() {
}}
```

Comment: Were is the editor getting this data that you say is missing from?

Comment: Note that `createInitialLayout` will not be called in the second case, instead the perspective is restored from the persisted state. Your editor input class probably needs to support being persisted - see https://rajakannappan.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/eclipse-rcp-saving-editor-state-and.html

Comment: @greg-449 : Ok, thank you very much. Now my question is what to write in the `saveState`-method of the `IPersistableElement`. In this example [link] (http://rajakannappan.blogspot.de/2009/10/eclipse-rcp-how-to-save-view-layouts.html) the author puts the selections in the memento, but for me selections are irrelevant, I just need my items/buttons of the `createInitialLayout`-method. How can I save them?

Comment: That blog entry is about saving view states - a completely different thing. What you are doing is saving the editor input. You save whatever you need to recreate the editor input.

Comment: @greg-449: I read this blog entry about saving view states because under item 4 of the blog entry about saving editor states it says that the 'saveState'-method works for editors like it works for views. I don't know how to put my items/buttons, what is the only relevant thing for my special editor, in the 'IMemento'. Therefore I searched in the article about saving view states for some help. Could you possibly give me a little code snippet example how to do this, please?

Comment: The only things you save in the editor input are the inputs to the editor - things like the file to editor. It is just used to create a new editor input (`BDDEditorInput` in your case)

Comment: @greg-449: Yes, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added in `Extensions` `ElementFactory` like you can see here[ElementFactory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McL6e.png). This is my code for the ElementFactory:

```
public class ElementFactory implements IElementFactory, IAdaptable {

String ID = "bdd.klighd.factory";

@Override
public IAdaptable createElement(IMemento memento) {
    return new BDDEditorInput("test of editor input");
}

@Override
public <T> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

and this is my code for the EditorInput:

```
public class BDDEditorInput implements IStorageEditorInput, IPersistableElement {

private final String inputString;

public BDDEditorInput(String inputString) {
    this.inputString = inputString;
}

public boolean exists() {
    return true;
}

public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor() {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void saveState(IMemento memento) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public String getFactoryId() {
    return "bdd.klighd.factory";
}

public IPersistableElement getPersistable() {
    return this;
}

public IStorage getStorage() throws CoreException {
    return new IStorage() {
        public InputStream getContents() throws CoreException {
            return new StringBufferInputStream(inputString);
        }

        public IPath getFullPath() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return BDDEditorInput.this.getName();
        }

        public boolean isReadOnly() {
            return false;
        }

        public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public Object getAdapter(Class adapter) {
    return null;
}

public String getName() {
    return "input name";
}

public String getToolTipText() {
    return "BDD Editor";
}
```

}

Yeah, it works, my items/buttons are visible now. But I don't know why, because I did not implement them in the EditorInput-class. However, it works!